# How to bind a draggable event to multiple instances after using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, inventory

I'm trying to make an inventory system with lots of slots, and I think that I'm doing something wrong. Is it the same calling ".draggable()" on each element like that or is it faster to group up all the elements and then apply it to them all? if so how can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
 for (x=0; x<100; x++){

    var $slots = $('<div class="slot">'+(x+1)+'</div>').appendTo('#inventory').draggable();

 }
```

Thanks in advance,

Thaiscorpion

Comment: Is $('#Element') .draggable() the proper way to make an element draggable?

Comment: If so, I would create a separate function like so  $('.slot').live(function(){$(this).draggable();});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a test:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

for (x=0; x<1000; x++){

    $('<div class="slot">'+(x+1)+'</div>').appendTo('#inventory').draggable();

}
var time_spent = new Date().getTime() - start;
$('#results').append("Time spend if draggable applied on each slot: " + ( time_spend / 1000 ) + "s");

start = new Date().getTime();
for (x=0; x<1000; x++){

   $('<div class="slot">'+(x+1)+'</div>').appendTo('#inventory');

}
$('.slot').draggable();
time_spent = new Date().getTime() - start;
$('#results').append("<br/>Time spend if draggable applied on all slots: " + ( time_spend / 1000 ) + "s");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gael/4KSmd/1/

Results for x = 0 to 10000:

Time spend if draggable applied on each slot: 12.957s

Time spend if draggable applied on all slots: 140.269s

Comment: Great works perfect Gael it fixes my probelm but also that example is really useful for me to see how to do tests like these thanks!

Comment: it's fine if it helps you! If you need performances, using jquery draggable could not be the best way. http://caniuse.com/dragndrop

Comment: Yeah I will check that out, one thing the results you are getting from the test are very very different to mine:

Time spend if draggable applied on each slot: 5.308s
Time spend if draggable applied on all slots: 5.211s

This was with 10000 each.

Comment: The test may be for 100,000 values. I've found that for small value, the difference is small but it increases significantly in favor of the first method. It could also depends on browser implementations.